# win 7 explore does not work

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I recently had to expand the size of my system partition because of a stupid setup. This went fine and insted of having C: with ~75gb and D: with ~825gb i now have a C: with ~900gb.

And everything is working except a small and annoying thing!

I cant access explorer via shortcuts from applications (Outlook wont let me browser after my old PST files, my bookkeeping program wont let me jump from the program to a specific folder in explorer) All of these functionalities worked before, so it must have been the merging of the two partitions that screwed something up!

When use the term "shortcuts" i dont mean the traditional shortcuts, i mean a function inside an applications that leads me to a specific folder via windows explorer!

It is not a path problem, D: was only used to store music and pictures!

Comment: Your theory is unlikely.  WHat is more likely is the shortcuts you were using were pointing to the your other drive.  Since the drive no longer exists they are not longer valid.  Provide us the target path to one of the broken shortcuts.

Comment: They did not point to the other drive D: was mearly storage for music and pictures. I cant give you the target paths, its functions in the applications, in outlook its add outlook data file and in the booking program it is a buildin function

Comment: Update the question with the requested information.  The only thing I know for a fact is this isn't an `Windows x86` `Windows x64` issue mainly because you didnt reinstally Windows.  So if it was working before and nothing else changed then it can't be something like that.

Answer (score 1):

If in those programs the default (or last attempt to access the "shortcuts") was on D: it can be that you will need the D: again to change these defaults (besides re-installing those applications).

You can try creating a small D: drive or map D: to your own C:.

To map D: to your C: you can start a `cmd.exe` (Start/type cmd/choose cmd.exe at the top) and type `SUBST D: C:\` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Type `exit` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit the command prompt. You will now have a D:-drive. (same as C:). You can check in the explorer.

Now you can try to access those "shortcuts" in your applications (and change it/or choose somthing on C:).

To undo the mapping of D: you can do `SUBST D: /D` in the command prompt (cmd.exe) followed by `exit` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.